# Android Emulator failing to open on MAC from command line as well as from AVD Manager

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, macos-catalina, android-sdk-tools

Below error I get when trying to launch a emulator from terminal on MAC

```
user ~ $ emulator -list-avds
Pixel_4_play
user ~ $ emulator @Pixel_4_play
emulator: Android emulator version 30.7.4.0 (build_id 7453540) (CL:N/A)
handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf
cannot add library /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib: failed
added library /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libvulkan.dylib
cannot add library /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib: failed
added library /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/lib64/vulkan/libMoltenVK.dylib
emulator: INFO: GrpcServices.cpp:315: Started GRPC server at 127.0.0.1:8554, security: Local
emulator: INFO: EmulatorAdvertisement.cpp:93: Advertising in: /Users/akumar8/Library/Caches/TemporaryItems/avd/running/pid_61379.ini
dyld: lazy symbol binding failed: Symbol not found: _preadv
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

dyld: Symbol not found: _preadv
  Referenced from: /Users/user/Library/Android/sdk/emulator/qemu/darwin-x86_64/qemu-system-x86_64
  Expected in: /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib

Abort trap: 6
```

Also tried using AVD Manager, it still fails to launch a emulator. I get error saying "The emulator process for AVD was killed"

Could someone please help me with this.

My Mac info:
MAC OS Catalina - 10.15.7

Comment: It's a known bug https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/191799887

Comment: Thank you. For the update.

Answer (score 0):

Finally the issue is resolved.

A new update version - 30.8.4 is available now for Android Emulator which resolved the issue for me.

##### How to Update:

Please go to Android Studio > Tools > SDK Manager

Once SDK Manager opens, choose Android SDK from left
Now choose SDK Tools tab from right.

Search for Android Emulator to update it to 30.8.4 version.

Done.

Now open AVD Manager and launch emulator. It would work as expected.